# Using VBA arrange value in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have some queries related to the VBA script. I have a large number of data in an excel file These all are formula-based values so I can't use special cell functions as well.

[image: Please see the format]

Now I need a VBA script that will arrage the table in a proper way. I need if there is any cell blank then the value in the next cell will move left.
Like the below image.

[image]

Currently, I'm using the below code but it's taking too much time as its' looping through the entire database one by one. Is there any better way to perform this?

```
lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Repeat = 4
For cellno = 1 To Repeat
For rowno = 2 To lastrow
'Debug.Print cellno
'Debug.Print rowno


If Range(Col1 & rowno).Value = "" Then
Range(Col2 & rowno).Cut
Range(Col1 & rowno).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If


If Range(Col2 & rowno).Value = "" Then
Range(Col3 & rowno).Cut
Range(Col2 & rowno).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If


If Range(Col3 & rowno).Value = "" Then
Range(Col4 & rowno).Cut
Range(Col3 & rowno).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Range(Col4 & rowno).Value = "" Then
Range(Col5 & rowno).Cut
Range(Col4 & rowno).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next rowno
Next cellno
```

Comment: Welcome to VBA, yes as you see read and/or write to table is pretty slow, even with best possible algorithm (that is just the way Excel is); If possible, I suggest switching from VBA to a Database, if not, have patience. **Note** that it's NOT caused by VBA, it's because of reading and/or writing on the table.

Comment: Do you need to move just the value?  Or do you also have to move the formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the values, and not the underlying formulas, Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365) may be a better option.  Certainly should be faster.

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

The basic algorithm consists of:

- Transpose the table
- Remove the nulls (blanks) from each column
- Transpose the table back

*PQ has an easier time removing nulls from columns and collapsing them than from rows*

**M Code**

```
let
   //Change Table name in next line to your actual table (or range) name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],

    //Demote the headers, then transpose the table
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Source),
    tt = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"),

    /*convert each column into a list,
       remove the nulls from the list,
       then recreate the table from the list of columns */
    remNulls = let 
        colNames = Table.ColumnNames(tt),
        cols = List.Generate(
            ()=> [col = List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column(tt,colNames{0})), i=1],
            each [i] <= Table.RowCount(tt),
            each [col = List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column(tt,colNames{[i]})) , i = [i]+1],
            each [col])
        in 
            Table.FromColumns(cols),

    //transpose the table back to original and promote the headers        
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(remNulls),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

    //set data types to Text (could do something different if needed)
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),each {_, Text.Type}))
in
    typeIt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Moving the data to a Variant Array, looping that, then moving the data back to the range will speed this up a lot.

Since you are dealing with Formulas, use `Range.Formula2` to get the data (or `Range.Formula` if you are not using a version of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays)

```vb
Sub Demoz()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long, idx As Long
    
    ' Get a reference to your Data range
    Set rng = Workbooks("YourWorkbook").Worksheets("YourWorksheet").Range("YourDataRange")
    
    ' Move data to a Variant Array
    '   Dynamic Array versions of Excel
    dat = rng.Formula2 '
    '   Non-Dynamic Array versions of Excel
    'dat = rng.Formula
    
    ' Loop the Data Array
    For rw = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        ' Find first blank column in current row
        idx = 0
        For cl = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
            If dat(rw, cl) = vbNullString Then
                idx = cl
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
        ' If row contains some blanks
        If idx > 0 Then
            ' Loop the row
            For cl = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
                ' If cell contains data
                If dat(rw, cl) <> vbNullString Then
                    ' If cell needs to be moved
                    If idx < cl Then
                        ' Move cell to the left most empty cell
                        dat(rw, idx) = dat(rw, cl)
                        dat(rw, cl) = Empty
                        idx = idx + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Place results back on sheet
    '   Dynamic Array versions of Excel
    rng.Formula2 = dat
    '   Non-Dynamic Array versions of Excel
    'rng.Formula = dat
    
End Sub
```

On my hardware a range of 100,000 rows, 10 columns is processed in about 3 seconds.  YMMV

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, Thanks for the help but sorry to inform you but this solution is not perfect. ``` If dat(rw, cl) = vbNullString Then``` this line check if cell content formula aur not. I would like to inform you that there are formulas in every cell. I need to check if the formulated cell is blank or not. if yes then move to left

Comment: @mdarshadali well, that's a detail that would have been useful in your question.   I'd approach that by making two Variant Arrays, one for the Formulas and one for the Values.  Test the Values for `= vbNullString`, and if found, move the Formula

Answer (score -1):

This example combined with what you have may speed up the process a bit, rather than using cut and paste it shifts the data around. Also note the use of IsEmpty.

Sorry I couldn't type up a full working example, computer is on the fritz at the moment and using an email or something was making me lose my concentration while trying.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/loop-through-data-using-macro